# Integration test a routes template in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I have an ember-cli 2.4.2 application that contains a route `myroute` and a template `myroute.hbs`.

When I integration test components, I do something like this,

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('mycomponent', 'Integration | Component | mycomponent', {
    integration: true
});

test('the component', function(assert) {
    this.render(hbs`
        {{#mycomponent}}
            text
        {{/mycomponent}}
    `);

    assert.notEqual(this.$('.container').text().trim(), 'text');
});
```

When I use `moduleFor('route:myroute')`, the call `this.render()` throws `this.render is not a function`. As below, if I call `route.render()` it throws `Error: Assertion Failed: Could not find "hbs{{myroute}}" template, view, or component.`

The goal is to integration test a route's template. I'd like to use jQuery to ensure the template rendered correctly. I have some computed properties on the route that influence what's displayed.

I can't seem to find any good documentation on integration testing a routes template. Any ideas or pointers? Many thanks.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleFor('route:myroute', 'Integration | Route | myroute', {
    integration: true,
});

test('the route', function(assert) {
    const mockModel = {
        response: { field1: true, field2: false }
    };

    const route = this.subject({ model: mockModel });

    route.render(`hbs{{myroute}}`);

    // ...
});
```

Comment: There is a typo—the `hbs` should be outside the backticks. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to solve the problem is to use acceptance tests where you can use jQuery and also navigate to certain routes in your application. You also get async helpers there like `andThen`, `visit`. Please refer to [Ember Guides on Acceptance Testing](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/acceptance/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is working out nicely. I ran into some issues because the route queries an API, so I spent some time faking the API with `ember-cli-mirage`. http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/quickstart/

Comment: Sure, testing when AJAX requests and async code is involved requires some time to get it working from my experience :) Especially when app is complex and each route has lots of dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to test template of a route, use [acceptance tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/acceptance/).

If you need to test methods and computed properties of a route, use [unit tests](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-routes/).